# PHP Curl API - Cookies on remote server not working when using curl

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I'm trying to create an API and access it using PHP.

This is my code to access the page - login.php

```
$postValues = http_build_query($postValues);
echo $postValues;

$curl = curl_init();
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => https://mywebsite.com/index.php,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postValues,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
    //CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $authUserAgent,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'cookies.txt',
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => 'cookies.txt',
);
curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
curl_exec($curl);

 //The remote page I would like to access
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://mywebsite.com/login-home.php');


$test = curl_exec($curl);
print_r($test);

curl_reset($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

This is my code to login the page - login.php

```
if(
    ($_POST['first_name'] == 'secret-word-1') AND 
    ($_POST['second_name'] == 'secret-word-2') AND 
    ($_POST['third_name'] == 'secret-word-3')

){
    echo 'Everything is correct';
    $setcookie = setcookie('books-login-cookie', 'books-cookie-value', time() + (100),'/');
}


if(isset($setcookie)){
    echo $setcookie;
    header('Location: login-home.php');
}else{
    echo 'No cookies!';
}

if(isset($setcookie)){
    echo $setcookie;
}else{
    echo 'Cookie cannot be set';
}

echo '<pre>';
echo $_COOKIE['books-login-cookie'];

print_r($setcookie);
echo '</pre>';
```

This is the code to validate the login form - login-val.php

```
if(
    ($_POST['first_name'] == 'secret-word-1') AND 
    ($_POST['second_name'] == 'secret-word-2') AND 
    ($_POST['third_name'] == 'secret-word-3')

){
    echo 'Everything is correct';
    $setcookie = setcookie('books-login-cookie', 'books-cookie-value', time() + (100),'/');
}

ECHO $setcookie;


if(isset($setcookie)){
    echo $setcookie;
    header('Location: login-home.php');
}else{
    echo 'No cookies!';
}

if(isset($setcookie)){
    echo $setcookie;
}else{
    echo 'Cookie cannot be set';
}

echo '<pre>';
echo $_COOKIE['books-login-cookie'];

print_r($setcookie);
echo '</pre>';
```

This is my secure page that I'm supposed to reach - login-home.php

```
<?php

echo '<h1>SECURE PAGE</h1>';

$setcookie = null;
if(isset($_COOKIE['books-login-cookie'])){
    $setcookie = $_COOKIE['books-login-cookie'];
    echo 'Cookie monster is happy!';
}else{
    echo 'No cookies on SECURE PAGE!';
    header('Location: login.php');

}

echo '<pre>';
echo $setcookie;

print_r($_COOKIE);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

When I try to use cURL - I get "No cookies on SECURE PAGE!" meaning that the cURL code is redirected to the restricted page however cookies aren't set. In the meantime, if I had to go directly to login.php I get "Cookie monster is happy!". This means that the cookies work as they are supposed to.

The files cookies.txt permission is set to 777. I can't understand why it isn't working.

I'm not interested in security as I'm just tinkering around for the time being.

Comment: cookies will work only if browser operations are done. CURL is not browser operation.

Comment: How can I go about it please?

Comment: Cookies aren't available until the next request  they are sent with.

Comment: It seems that nothing is being written to cookies.txt to be able to read them.

Comment: You also have followlocation set to false, yet have redirects in your API(?) code? Frankly, it's not obvious what is being called when and by what, so it's difficult to help. Not even really sure what you're trying to achieve with this odd setup.

Comment: As far as I can tell, your curl request calls `login-home.php`. Let's assume you start with no cookie. So you do a header redirect to `login.php` but you don't have follow location on, so probably doesn't get called. The cookies gets set in `login.php` so because that's never called, you never get one.